# Making a NANDROID backup of a device with broken touchscreen

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, nandroid, acer-iconia-a500

This is the first of a series of questions about "the broken tablet saga". Basically I have an Acer A500 with broken touchscreen to get ready for warranty. I won't ask all of my questions in a single topic.

I want to make a full backup of my tablet without using the touchscreen. The tablet is rooted.

How do I - **without using the touchscreen** - make a NANDROID backup of it to be restored on the replacement device Acer will hopefully send to me? (Or just to restore the repaired tablet)

I currently don't have the device in my hands. I suppose it is equipped with the classic ClockworkMod recovery. As a backup plan, I would like to know what can I do to install ClockworkMod without touchscreen support.

I'll have the device in my hands in a few hours. I would like to be prepared for that (including downloading any additional software or firmware from an unlimited data connection)

[Update] I must install CWM **without** using Acer Recovery Installer. I can't find a link to a binary and instructions on how to flash a recovery (there are plenties of tutorials for download mode on Samsungs)

Comment: What recovery are you using? Presumably the touch recovery variants or the plain old Clockwork Mod Recovery?

Comment: @t0mm13b question updated. I suppose the plain old Clockwork or the stock

Answer (score 1):

The "*classic* CWM" does not even support the touch screen. It is operated solely via hardware keys -- usually the volume up/down keys to navigate, and the power button to confirm actions. On devices featuring a trackball (as the "classic [htc-wildfire](/questions/tagged/htc-wildfire) for example), this can be used as well to scroll the menus and confirm actions.

<sup>Note that there's also a touch-enabled CWM available -- but that's not the "classical one".</sup>

However, if your device comes from the manufacturer, it is **not** equipped with [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod), but with a stock recovery. Stock recovery does **not** support [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backups. So you would first need to flash the recovery in order to use that. Depending on the device, there may be different installation instructions (and different requirements), so make sure to check that first. CWM would then replace the existing "3e" recovery located on the `/recovery` partition, but should leave the other parts (e.g. your `/data` and `/system`) intact.

Answer (score 0):

Need a more concrete answer - the stock recovery is very different to CWM (Clockwork Mod) in that stock recovery cannot do what CWM can do!

As for asking *what can I do to install ClockworkMod without touchscreen support* you will have to re-flash the device with a custom boot/recovery/system, **inevitably** you will lose everything when that's carried out.

I could suggest, let the device boot up, and try get a rom-dumper tool installed into `/data/local/tmp` by way of shell script or similar tool that will save the data that would be compatible with Clockwork Mod (Disclaimer: you are on your own [here](http://forum.tegraowners.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=388)), you are rooted anyway at least! :)

Comment: I cannot remember that installing CWM lost me a single thing. Why should it flash `/system`? CWM is a recovery, and thus goes to `/recovery`. It might touch `/boot`, but it certainly will not *overwrite* `/system`.

Comment: CWM comes with custom ROM and custom boot, they are usually tied in together. As for flashing CWM, boot loader needs to be unlocked :)

Comment: Since when does CWM come with a Custom ROM? I have CWM on multiple devices. My ROMs where never touched, just the "3e" recovery got replaced (could it be you confuse "CWM" (ClockworkMod) with "CM" (CyanogenMod) here?). The part concerning the bootloader, however, most likely is correct -- if it is locked, that is. Not all devices ship with a locked bootloader :)

Comment: Not confusing with CM! :) To flash a custom recovery requires unlocked boot, in *order* to "get in" at it to do it, generally :) And in order to "get in" requires a unlocked boot loader...

Comment: Unlocked bootloader yes, full ack as I wrote. But you will **not** *have to re-flash the device with a custom boot/recovery/system* (at least `/system` is wrong here). But instead of a lengthy discussion here, we better settle that in chat, if you don't mind, and then just add the results back here?

Comment: I actually need to find out how to flash CWM since **it's not installed** at this time and installing it on a rooted device requires an app, which ultimately requires touchscreen